# Read file_path from dictionary and use another key-value pair later in the pipeline

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a data ingestion pipeline which consist of multiple folders and multiple files within each folder.

**What is working:**
I have managed to get a PCollection of dictionaries from the file structure in the following format:

```
{'filepath': 'filename1.parquet', 
'table_name': 'company'}

{'filepath': 'filename2.parquet', 
'table_name': 'users'}
.
.
.
```

**QUESTION**

How do I split the pipeline in such a way that I can read the parquet file and later in the pipeline use the table_name for bigquery dynamic destination?

**What I have tried:**

1. Flatmaps : I ended up getting cross joins between each data row of parquet file with the table name which is a mess.
2. Side input: Since number of data rows in each parquet file in unknown, I have no idea how to access and use the table name during bigquery sink

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

        readable_files = (p
                          | 'Create' >> fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern=known_args.input)
                          | 'Read Matches' >> fileio.ReadMatches()
                          )

        files_and_contents = (readable_files |
                              beam.Map(lambda x: x.metadata.path)
                             )

        # result contains the dictionary as mentioned above
        result = (
             files_and_contents
             | 'Extract filename and tablename from path' >> beam.Map(extract_filename)
             )

        parquet_reads = (
            result
            | "Get Parquet filename" >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['filepath']))
            | 'Read All Files' >> beam.io.ReadAllFromParquet()
        )

        (
         parquet_reads
         | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery('{0}:{1}'.format(PROJECT, BQ_DATASET_NAME),
                                schema=SCHEMA,
                                table= <HOW DO I GET THIS VALUE FROM THE DICT?> ,
                                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,                                         
                                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is the `ReadFromTextWithFilename` equivalent of `ReadAllFromParquet`, which doesn't look like it exists (though wouldn't be too hard to [add](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/)). In the meantime, as your set of tables looks neither that large nor that dynamic, you could expand and read `known_args.input` in your main program, and for each dictionary do an ordinary `ReadFromParquet` followed by a `WriteToBigQuery` where the table name (and any other information) is now known.